# How to implement animated images/icons on a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, web

I want to build a website with animated images, like the one in dropbox homepage:

https://www.dropbox.com/

Another example is the intro images in treehouse homepage:

http://teamtreehouse.com/

I think maybe I can use javascript and jQuery to dynamically change the images and their positions, but I am not sure.
I wonder if there is any library or technology available to implement this kind of animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple animations you probably want to use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) to animate CSS properties like "left" or "top".

```
@keyframes slidein {
  from { left: 450px; }
  to { left: 0; }
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eihJs

Comment: Thanks a lots! That is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Or can just move images inside your div or you can use SVG like here:
[Link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/30/svg-drawing-animation/)

Comment: Thanks Vega! This is very helpful too!